# jQuery.when: Get the xhr status code

Tags: jquery, ajax, .when

I have two ajax calls that executes some callback after both of them get completed using [jQuery.when()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)

```
$.when(loadDataA(), loadDataB()).done(function(dataA, dataB) {
  console.log(xhr.status); // How do I get the xhr.status?
}
```

I want to know the `xhr.status` of the first call. With the normal .done() you can do something like:

```
.done(function(data, statusText, xhr) {
  console.log(xhr.status);
}
```

But I can not make it work in my case.

How do I get it when using `jQuery.when`?

Comment: if you have multiple xhr request you will need to have multiple stats

Comment: I thought so. Do you have an example on how to do that?

Comment: if there's no built-in functionality for that (didn't find any), i would try to make loadDataA and B return an object that contains the xhr status with the data. You could then retreive it from dataA and dataB.. just an idea

Comment: `dataA` is an array with all passed parameters. `dataA[2]` is the `XMLHttpRequest` object ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3yjjhfh4/))

Comment: @Andreas yours is the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation for [`$.when()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/):

*In the event a Deferred was resolved with no value, the corresponding doneCallback argument will be undefined. If a Deferred resolved to a single value, the corresponding argument will hold that value. In the case where a Deferred resolved to multiple values, **the corresponding argument will be an array of those values**. For example:*

```
var d1 = $.Deferred();
var d2 = $.Deferred();
var d3 = $.Deferred();

$.when( d1, d2, d3 ).done(function ( v1, v2, v3 ) {
    console.log( v1 ); // v1 is undefined
    console.log( v2 ); // v2 is "abc"
    console.log( v3 ); // v3 is an array [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
});

d1.resolve();
d2.resolve( "abc" );
d3.resolve( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 );
```

In your case `dataA` will be an array with three elements:

```
dataA[0] -> data
dataA[1] -> statusText
dataA[2] -> xhr
```

With this...

> How do I get it when using jQuery.when?

`dataA[2].status`